# Fire job cron immediately with quartz

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I tried fire job cron immediately with quartz but not working.
Obs: this job exists in my database.

this is my code that used to fire job immediately:

```
public class ExecuteJob {

   public static void now(String TriggerKey) throws SchedulerException {

       scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

        // retrieve the trigger
        Trigger oldTrigger = scheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey(TriggerKey, GROUP_JOB));

        scheduler.triggerJob(oldTrigger.getJobKey());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you shure the scheduler is started (`scheduler.start()` has been called and no shutdown or standby command has been done)?

Comment: so triggerJob should it start my job immediately and shutdown after job finished, no?

if called start method, my job enter in infinite loop. even if call shutdown method below start method.

Comment: I guess you need a running scheduler even for immediate start. Try call `scheduler.start()` before firing `triggerJob`.

Comment: I tried your solution, and works fine, thank you :).

Comment: posted the solution in below comment.

Answer (score 0):

The solution final is:

```
public static void now(String TriggerKey) throws SchedulerException {
    scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

    Trigger oldTrigger = scheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey(TriggerKey, GROUP_JOB));

    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.triggerJob(oldTrigger.getJobKey());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentionend in the comments, you need ensure the scheduler is started even for immediate job starts.

You can check this using the `isStarted()` method in combination with 'isInStandbyMode()' and 'isShutdown()' methods.
Note that [`isStarted`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#isStarted()) "only reflects whether start() has ever been called on this Scheduler, so it will return true even if the Scheduler is currently in standby mode or has been since shutdown".

To start the scheduler use the `start()` method:

```
public static void now(String TriggerKey) throws SchedulerException {

   scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

    // retrieve the trigger
    Trigger oldTrigger = scheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey(TriggerKey, GROUP_JOB));

    // start the scheduler
    if (!scheduler.isStarted() || scheduler.isInStandbyMode() || scheduler.isShutdown())
        scheduler.start() 

    scheduler.triggerJob(oldTrigger.getJobKey());
}
```